# Set value of XSLT parameter with if statement

Tags: xslt

I'm applying a template with a parameter of householdID. I'd like to check to see if a value for @householdID exists or is null, and if it is null, set the value of the parameter to zero. Otherwise, use the value of the existing variable.

```
<xsl:with-param name="householdID">
   <xsl:if test="not(@householdID)">
        0
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="@householdID">
        <xsl:value-of select="@householdID"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:with-param>
```

This does not appear to be working. I'm guessing it's an easy fix?

Comment: How exactly did you determine that "this does not appear to be working"? Please post a reproducible example - see: [mcve]. -- P.S. You should become familiar with `xsl:choose`.

Comment: A [mcve] would be very helpful.

Comment: It was not setting the value of the parameter to 0. Solved this by creating a variable $householdID prior to applying the template, which checked to see if there was a householdID, and if not, set the value of the householdID variable to 0, then setting value of the parameter to that variable.

Comment: @MattP That shouldn't make any difference. You're only adding an unnecessary complication, instead of identifying the real problem.